# How to generate multi bar chart in Chart.js with php & sql

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js, sqlsrv

i have a table named overall_summary which contain 4 fields - [Date], [Month/Year], [Dredger] and [Barge Volume].

I'm trying to generate a multi-bar chart to display total volume for each Dredger grouped by Date. Below is the code i have written to generate the graph:

PHP:

```
 <?php
        $datelist = "";
        $dredgelist = "";
        $volumedata = "";
        $datearray = "'2019-10-01";
        $title = "'Dredging Volume'";
        $chartype = "'bar'";
        $barcolor = "'rgb(252, 155, 155, 0.5)'";
        $x_title = "'Date'";
        $yline = "true";
        $xline = "false";
        $bkcolor = "#F5F5F5";

                    $sql_query = "SELECT [date], [Dredger], SUM([Barge Volume]) AS 'Dredging Volume' FROM OVERALL_SUMMARY_ORIGINAL 
                                         WHERE [Month/Year] in ($datearray) GROUP BY [Date], [Dredger] order by [Date], [Dredger]";
                    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql_query);

                    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC)){

                        $datelabel = $row[0]->format('Y/m/d');
                        $dredger = $row[1];
                        $vol = $row[2];

                        $datelist = $datelist."'".$datelabel."',";
                        $datelist_2 = trim($datelist,",");

                        $dredgelist = $dredgelist."'".$dredger."',";
                        $dredgelist_2 = trim($dredgelist,",");

                        $volumedata = $volumedata.$vol.",";
                        $volumedatalist = trim($volumedata,",");        
                    }

    ?>

    <canvas id="myChart2" style="background-color:<?php echo $bkcolor; ?>; height:400px;"></canvas>
```

Javascript

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

            /*****first chart********/
            var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart2').getContext('2d');
                var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type:<?php echo $chartype; ?>,
                    data : {
                      labels: [<?php echo $datelist_2; ?>], <!--label name->
                      datasets: [
                          { 
                            label: [<?php echo $dredgelist_2;?>],
                            data: [<?php echo $volumedatalist; ?>],
                            backgroundColor: <?php echo $barcolor; ?>
                          }               
                          ]
                    },
                    options: {
                        responsive: true,
                        maintainAspectRatio: false,
                        tooltips: {
                                   callbacks: {
                                       label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                                           return tooltipItem.yLabel.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");}}
                                }, 
                          scales: {
                            xAxes: [
                              { 
                                stacked: true ,
                                scaleLabel: {
                                    display: true,
                                    labelString: <?php echo $x_title; ?>,
                                    fontSize: 11,
                                    fontStyle: "bold"
                                },
                                ticks: {
                                    fontSize: 11
                                },
                                gridLines: {
                                    display: <?php echo $xline; ?>
                                }
                             }],
                            yAxes: [
                                { 
                                stacked: true,
                                scaleLabel: {
                                    display: true,
                                    labelString: 'Barge Volume (m3)',
                                    fontSize: 11,
                                    fontStyle: "bold"
                                },
                                ticks: {
                                    fontSize: 11,
                                    beginAtZero:true,
                                    userCallback: function(value, index, values) {
                                        value = value.toString();
                                        value = value.split(/(?=(?:...)*$)/);
                                        value = value.join(',');
                                        return value;
                                        }
                                    },
                                gridLines: {
                                    display: <?php echo $yline; ?>
                                }                           
                              }
                            ]
                          },
                          legend: {
                              display: true,
                              labels: {
                                  fontSize: 15,
                                  fontStyle: "bold",
                                  padding: 16
                              },
                              position: 'top'
                          },
                          title: {
                              display: true,
                              text: <?php echo $title; ?>,
                              fontSize: 15

                          },
                          plugins: {
                                  datalabels: {
                                     display: true,
                                     align: 'center',
                                     anchor: 'center'
                                  }
                               }
                        }

                    });



            </script>
```

However, the chart output i get looks like this which is not what i want
[image]

I trying to get the Chart js to produce a multi bar column chart which looks like this as shown below. How can i achieve that? I have been trying to resolve this for few days but to no avail. Can anyone guide me? Thanks

[image]

Comment: That's because you have all your data in a single dataset. You need multiple datasets, one for Atlas, one for Ebisu and so on. Whenever there are problems with data, it's very hard to help without seeing your data structure. Can you post the content of your arrays somehow?

Comment: I wanted to avoid creating multiple datasets as this will be fixed and not dynamic. but i have search for almost every where online for an answer but it seems this is not possible with 1 datasets. I have to use your method instead. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess the only way to do this is to create multiple datasets instead of one. This may not be the best answer but this is how i did it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            /*****first chart********/
            var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart2').getContext('2d');
                var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type:<?php echo $chartype; ?>,
                    data : {
                      labels: [<?php echo $datelist_2; ?>], <!--label name->
                      datasets: [
                          { 
                            label: [<?php echo $dredgelist_2;?>],
                            data: [<?php echo $volumedatalist; ?>],
                            backgroundColor: <?php echo $barcolor; ?>
                          },
                          { 
                            label: [<?php echo yourVariable;?>],
                            data: [<?php echo yourVariable; ?>],
                            backgroundColor: <?php echo yourColor; ?>
                          },
                          { 
                            label: [<?php echo yourVariable;?>],
                            data: [<?php echo yourVariable; ?>],
                            backgroundColor: <?php echo yourColor; ?>
                          },
                          { 
                            label: [<?php echo yourVariable;?>],
                            data: [<?php echo yourVariable; ?>],
                            backgroundColor: <?php echo yourColor; ?>
                          }               
                          ]
                    },
                    options: {
                        responsive: true,
                          ..............
                          .............
                          .........
</script>
```

[image]